# API Version not supported for storageAccount in Azure RM Powershell - No registered resource provider

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to update an event subscription endpoint by using Azure RM Powershell.

In Powershell I run following command:

`Update-AzureRmEventGridSubscription -EventSubscriptionName $eventSubName -ResourceId $subscriptionId -Endpoint $endpointUrl`

Problem is that the provider is not supporting this API version, so now I wonder, how I can force the command to use a specified API version. Is it possible, or what can I do to have this command work?

Following error occour:

> Update-AzureRmEventGridSubscription : No registered resource provider found for location 'northeurope' and API version '2018-01-01' for type 'storageAccounts'. The supported api-versions are '2018-07-01, 2018-03-01-preview, 2018-02-01, 2017-10-0
>   1, 2017-06-01, 2016-12-01, 2016-05-01, 2016-01-01, 2015-06-15, 2015-05-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'eastus, eastus2, westus, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, japaneast, japanwest, northcentralus, southcentralus, centralus, north
>   europe, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, southindia, centralindia, westindia, canadaeast, canadacentral, westus2, westcentralus, uksouth, ukwest, koreacentral, koreasouth, francecentral'

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that the location should be `north europe` and not `northeurope`.

Comment: The region must be pulled from the resource group, i suppepose, so nothing I set. In the error message they also use northeurope, so I think that's fine.

Comment: In the error message it says `north europe` - that was my whole point. I get that it might not be something you set yourself but that's a different story.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having what looks like a similar problem, although it doesn't mention the region name. Nevertheless, the error message is still complaining that the particular API version - which in this case is a preview version - doesn't have that provider name.

Comment: @TomW 
I don't remember how I solved this, but have you tried specified the API version to use by adding  -ApiVersion [api version to use], example:
```Update-AzureRmEventGridSubscription -EventSubscriptionName $eventSubName -ResourceId $subscriptionId -Endpoint $endpointUrl -ApiVersion 2018-07-01```